# Delete the json file after reading its content via JsonItemReader in Sping Batch

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-batch, nio

How to delete the json file after reading its content via JsonItemReader?

Below is the sample code of my JsonItemReader.

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public JsonItemReader<MyObj> myReader() {

    LOGGER.info(LOG_TEMPLATE,
            getClass().getSimpleName(),
            Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName(),
            "Inside Reader...");

    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    final JacksonJsonObjectReader<MyObj> jsonObjectReader = new JacksonJsonObjectReader<>(
            MyObj.class);
    jsonObjectReader.setMapper(mapper);

    final String filePath = config.getRootfolder() + SEPERATOR + inputInfo.getFileName();

    return new JsonItemReaderBuilder<MyObj>().jsonObjectReader(jsonObjectReader)
            .resource(new FileSystemResource(filePath))
            .name("myReader")
            .build();

}
```

Then i added a code in my JobListener that after job execution it will delete the said file. Here is the sample code.

```
@Override
    public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {

        if (jobExecution.getStatus() == BatchStatus.COMPLETED) {
            LOGGER.info(LOG_TEMPLATE,
                    getClass().getSimpleName(),
                    Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName(),
                    "Job Completed, verify results.");
        } else {
            LOGGER.error(LOG_TEMPLATE,
                    getClass().getSimpleName(),
                    Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName(),
                    "Job ended abnormally.");
        }

        try {
            Files.delete(Paths.get(config.getRootfolder() + "/" + inputInfo.getFileName()));
        } catch (final IOException ex) {

            LOGGER.error(LOG_TEMPLATE,
                    getClass().getSimpleName(),
                    Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName(),
                    ex.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

But i am getting an error that file is still open or still being read.

Comment: I added a comment on your answer (which I upvoted). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if this is the proper and efficient way of deleting the json file afer the JsonItemReader Step but this way works for me.

What i did was i created a new Step with Tasklet that deletes the said json file.
Here is the sample code.

Tasklet Class:

```
@Override
public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {

    LOGGER.info(LOG_TEMPLATE,
            getClass().getSimpleName(),
            Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName(),
            "Inside Delete Json File Tasklet");

    try {

        final String filePath = config.getRootfolder() + SEPARATOR + inputInfo.getFileName();
        Files.delete(Paths.get(filePath));

    } catch (final IOException ex) {

        LOGGER.error(LOG_TEMPLATE,
                getClass().getSimpleName(),
                Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName(),
                ex.getMessage());
    }

    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
}
```

Comment: You are hitting this issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/1500 (see links to duplicate issues as well). And indeed, removing the file from a listener does not work. Using a separate step for the cleanup as you did is the workaround until this issue is fixed.